# Unity - Adjusting Time.fixedDeltaTime for smooth Slow mo messes up Addforce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm slowing down time in my game using the two lines:

```
Time.timeScale = slowMotionSpeed;
Time.fixedDeltaTime = slowMotionSpeed * 0.02f;
```

and the slow motion works just fine, it is smooth just as it has to be.

The problem is though that I have a lot of `AddForce` utilities on the levels, like jumping, trampolines, wind etc and they are calculated so that the player needs very precise timing to get that right.

I noticed that after using it in slow motion instead of regular speed those trampolines don't take me far enough to make the jump no matter how many times I try (and it was an easy jump before that).

If I try the jump in slow motion, but **without** adjusting the `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, the game lags, but the jump is successful.

The question is, how to address this so that `AddForce` works fine and throws the player to the same distance, even if the `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is modified?

**Edit:**

the trampoline:

```
float jumpForceAdded;
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !CharacterController2D.movementDisabled && !CharacterController2D.playerDied)
    {
        Rigidbody2D otherRB = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (JumpInput.JUMP)
        {
            otherRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForceAdded * 2f));
        }
        else
        {
            otherRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForceAdded));
        }
        StartCoroutine(ChangeSpritesBack());
    }
}
```

It uses "double jump" if we jump on the trampoline, and just a regular jump if we don't.

**Edit again**:  I added the `Addforce` version which I should have added on the beginning. I used a deprecated one, sorry for the inconvenience.

By the way, as I'm using `OnTriggerStay2D`, my guess is that the force itself isn't different - but the duration while the player receives that force is. I don't know if proportionally changing the force based on time would work in all cases.

Comment: can you please add your code that contains `AddForce`.   
how about proportionally adjusting the force based on the fixedDeltaTime?
so while in slo-mo it sends a different force.

Comment: True, sorry. Editing right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify `Time.timeScale`, you *do **not** have to modify `Time.fixedDeltaTime`*. The reason your game appears to "lag" is because your rigidbodies are not interpolated. Set [`Rigidbody.interpolation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-interpolation.html) to [`RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate.html).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The lag I experience is for my camera that uses smooth follow (it gets its transform lerped, no rigidbodies there). 
Is there a way to get that sorted out as well?

Comment: Is the smooth follow cam following a rigidbody? If it is, make sure that the rigidbody is interpolated.

Comment: Indeed it follows one, namely the player character's rigidbody. 
Just set what you said in a `Start` or `Awake`?

Comment: If so, it doesn't work - it stutters like hell :/ (The cam follows the player character and I set its rigidbody to interpolate, just like you wrote)

Comment: Instead of setting it in Start or Awake, set it in the inspector itself. Also make sure the smooth follow script uses LateUpdate instead of FixedUpdate.

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html): *"If you lower `timeScale` it is recommended to also lower `Time.fixedDeltaTime` by the same amount."*.